# Activate unused hard disks

Tags: drivers, 17.10

```
┌─╼ [~/grive]
└────╼ sudo fdisk -l
[sudo] password for infinity: 
Disk /dev/sda: 223.6 GiB, 240057409536 bytes, 468862128 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: CBF0E7EB-2677-4D68-B9B5-C9212D0CF17A

Device       Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1     2048   1050623   1048576   512M EFI System
/dev/sda2  1050624   2549759   1499136   732M Linux filesystem
/dev/sda3  2549760 468860927 466311168 222.4G Linux filesystem


Disk /dev/sdb: 1.8 TiB, 2000398934016 bytes, 3907029168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x96196249

Device     Boot Start        End    Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1        2048 3907026943 3907024896  1.8T  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT


Disk /dev/sdc: 1.8 TiB, 2000398934016 bytes, 3907029168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x9619624a

Device     Boot Start        End    Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sdc1        2048 3907026943 3907024896  1.8T  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT




Disk /dev/mapper/sda3_crypt: 222.4 GiB, 238749220864 bytes, 466307072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root: 154.4 GiB, 165767282688 bytes, 323764224 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-swap_1: 67.9 GiB, 72926363648 bytes, 142434304 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/mapper/cryptswap1: 67.9 GiB, 72925839360 bytes, 142433280 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
┌─╼ [~/grive]
└────╼ df
Filesystem                  1K-blocks     Used Available Use% Mounted on
udev                         34978220        0  34978220   0% /dev
tmpfs                         7001324    10788   6990536   1% /run
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root 158291060 58315528  91865044  39% /
tmpfs                        35006608    41756  34964852   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                            5120        4      5116   1% /run/lock
tmpfs                        35006608        0  35006608   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda2                      721392   409920    259008  62% /boot
/dev/sda1                      523248     4736    518512   1% /boot/efi
tmpfs                         7001320       16   7001304   1% /run/user/121
tmpfs                         7001320       36   7001284   1% /run/user/1000
/home/infinity/.Private     158291060 58315528  91865044  39% /home/infinity
```

`sudo fdisk -l` made a list of all existing hard disks on my computer and `df -h` listed the hard disks use on my computer. I have two hard disks (i.e. `dev/sdb` and `dev/sdc`) with 1.8 TB of capacity, and I need them to be used on my computer.

How could I activate those hard disks so that I can use them? With not uninstalling anything if possible?

### UPDATE

```
┌─╼ [~]
└────╼ df -h
Filesystem                   Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev                          34G     0   34G   0% /dev
tmpfs                        6.7G   11M  6.7G   1% /run
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root  151G   56G   88G  39% /
tmpfs                         34G   17M   34G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                        5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs                         34G     0   34G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda2                    705M  401M  253M  62% /boot
/dev/sda1                    511M  4.7M  507M   1% /boot/efi
tmpfs                        6.7G   16K  6.7G   1% /run/user/121
tmpfs                        6.7G   20K  6.7G   1% /run/user/1000
/home/infinity/.Private      151G   56G   88G  39% /home/infinity
/dev/sdb1                    1.9T  235M  1.9T   1% /media/infinity/Document_2
/dev/sdc1                    1.9T  123M  1.9T   1% /media/infinity/Document_3
```

Comment: This is a cross-post of https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/437956/103151. Please decide on one site to ask your question and remove it from the other.

Comment: I didn't know it could be an issue. Ok, I did it on unix.stackexchange.com.

Comment: You may be confused. "Drivers" don't pertain to the disk information that you show. Please tell us **what problem that you're trying to solve** so that we can help.

Comment: @heynnema I need to activate my two hard disks `dev/sdb` and `dev/sdc` without uninstalling anything.

Comment: I think by activate, you _mount_.  At the command line try: `sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt` and see if you can see the volume.  E.g. if the mount command is successful, try `ls /mnt`.  You might also want to post the contents of `/etc/fstab`?  In particular, let's see if the installer write config lines for these volumes.

Comment: I will show you the output in the question in 30 seconds.

Comment: Ok, that looks good.  It looks like @heynnema has already pushed the answer I would have given you.   Use instructions in the answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**To mount the sdb and sdc disks at boot time...**

In `terminal`...

`sudo blkid` # show UUID's

- note the UUID's for sdb and sdc.

`sudo cp /etc/fstab /etc/fstab.bck` # to create a backup

`sudo pico /etc/fstab` # start the editor

- add three lines that look something like this...

`# ntfs disks`

`UUID=8E3A804C3A8032EF /media/infinity/Document_2 ntfs-3g defaults 0 0`

`UUID=to_be_determined /media/infinity/Document_3 ntfs-3g defaults 0 0`

- change the UUID to the values found in `blkid`
- change the your_username (to infinity)
- change the "Document_2" and "Document_3" names, if needbe

<kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd> # to save edits

<kbd>return</kbd> # to confirm filename

<kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> # to exit the editor

`sudo mount -a` # to mount the disks

Comment: your_username is shown in the `terminal` prompt, before the `@`... probably something like "jeremie". sdb_Data and sdc_Data are the volume names that you want displayed... like "Movies" and "Development".

Comment: Yes, of course.

Comment: I will show you my development in my question if it doesn't work. Thanks!

Comment: No. Use 8E3A804C3A8032EF, which is the UUID for sdb, and you've changed sdc since your question, so you'll need to redo it like you originally did, and then it'll show a proper UUID. You'll want to change the partition label from "New Volume" to something more representative.

Comment: You originally showed sdb and sdc as ntfs volumes. Now sdc shows as a raid volume. If you used gparted to init the drives and create new partitions, (assuming that you have no data there) repeat that process on both drives, and name the ntfs partitions Document_2 and Document_3. Use GUID partition tables if the drives are >2GB.

Comment: As I mentioned, somehow you've inited/used sdc as a RAID member, so to mount it like sdb, you'll have to use gparted to reinit it and create a new ntfs partition.

Comment: Start `gparted`. Create a new GUID device partition table on /dev/sdc. Then create a new ntfs partition named Document_3.

Comment: Follow my last comment.

Comment: I have modified my question so that you can see the output related to `df -h`. It did not work if I want to replace `/media/infinity/Document_2`. I wish to increase the memory of  `/home/infinity/.Private` from `152G` to `151G + 1.9T + 1.9 = 3.951T`. Is it possible? What do you suggest?

Comment: @Jeremie if your final goal was to make your /.Private larger by adding two 2TB disks to it, you should have said so earlier, 'cause that requires a different approach. What does making /.Private=3.95TB any different than using the disks mounted separately as you're doing now. If you still want to do that, I'd recommend using LVM disks... but that's a whole new question.

Comment: Ok, I will create a new question soon and inform you about it. Thanks again for you question.

Comment: Here is the new question :  https://askubuntu.com/questions/1025522/make-home-infinity-private-larger